# Stop Eclipse Command Line Pop Ups

Tags: eclipse

I am writing a small FLTK (GUI) program on windows 7 using Eclipse Kepler. My "int main()" function is not even set to receive any command line arguments, yet every time I build the program exe and run it a command line pops up being the GUI interface.

Does anyone know how to suppress this? I do not need a console display for any input or output etc. as this is all controlled via the GUI interface.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean console instead of command line? I guess you talk about the black window where you can read the stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to see with eclipse. It's a standard behaviour of c++ applications on Windows. Look for `console` on this [page](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.0/osissues.html). You will find how to disable it.

Comment: Thanks ybanen. Your link gave me a few more keywords to google which quickly led me to a solution. I basically added "-mwindows" to the linker flags in the miscellaneous section. I believe you may also need to include the "gdi32" and "comdlg32" libraries (which I had anyway due to using FLTK).